# Почему не работает ЧПУ битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!
По какой то причине не работает каталог на сайте, грешу на ЧПУ.
index файл каталога:

```
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
global $APPLICATION;
if($APPLICATION->GetCurDir()=="/shop/catalog/")
{
    //localRedirect('/shop/catalog/section/vse/');
    $pageCur = $APPLICATION->GetCurUri();
    $pageNew = str_replace("/shop/catalog/", "", $pageCur);
    //localRedirect('/shop/catalog/section/vse/'.$pageNew);
    //echo $pageNew;
}
?>
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog", 
    "main_custom", 
    array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "7",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SEF_FOLDER" => "/shop/catalog/",
        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
            "sections" => "",
            "section" => "section/#SECTION_CODE#/",
            "element" => "#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
            "compare" => "compare.php?action=#ACTION_CODE#",
            "smart_filter" => "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/filter/#SMART_FILTER_PATH#/apply/",
        ),
    ),
    false
);?>
<?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

[Настройки ИБ](https://prnt.sc/180yape)
urlrewrite:

```
<?php
$arUrlRewrite=array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/bitrix/services/ymarket/([\\w\\d\\-]+)?(/)?(([\\w\\d\\-]+)(/)?)?#',
    'RULE' => 'REQUEST_OBJECT=$1&METHOD=$4',
    'ID' => '',
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/ymarket/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/personal/history-of-orders/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:sale.personal.order',
    'PATH' => '/personal/history-of-orders/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/contacts/stores/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/contacts/stores/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/contacts/stores/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog.store',
    'PATH' => '/contacts/stores/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/personal/order/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:sale.personal.order',
    'PATH' => '/personal/order/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/info/articles/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/info/articles/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  19 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/shop/catalog/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog',
    'PATH' => '/shop/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/info/article/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/info/article/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/info/brands/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/info/brands/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/info/brand/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/info/brand/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/services/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/services/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/products/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog',
    'PATH' => '/products/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/article/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/article/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/catalog/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog',
    'PATH' => '/catalog/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/blog/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:blog',
    'PATH' => '/blog/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  15 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/sale/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/sale/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  16 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/news/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/news/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  18 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/rest/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => NULL,
    'PATH' => '/bitrix/services/rest/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
  17 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/buy/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:news',
    'PATH' => '/buy/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
);
```

Comment: а что конкретно не работает? (ссылки не те генерируются, или чпушные ссылки отдают 404 или там редиректит?)

Comment: Сама страница /shop/ открывается нормально, но если перейти в любую категорию/товар то отображается главная страница, но при этом ссылка в адресной строке стоит верная

Comment: тогда возможно в main_custom какие-то проблемы, а если дефолтный шаблон потестить, чпу норм работает?

Comment: С дефолтным шаблоном та же беда

Comment: а проверяли работу urlrewrite? может .htaccess не отрабатывает или криво настроен?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала `urlrewrite.php`

```php
19 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/shop/catalog/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog',
    'PATH' => '/shop/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
```

Тут ключ condition указывает на `/shop/catalog/`, а исполняемый файл в `/shop/index.php` ? Может правильней будет так:

```php
19 => 
  array (
    'CONDITION' => '#^/shop/catalog/#',
    'RULE' => '',
    'ID' => 'bitrix:catalog',
    'PATH' => '/shop/catalog/index.php',
    'SORT' => 100,
  ),
```

Далее сам файл `/shop/catalog/index.php` в котором у вас сейчас вот это:

```php
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:catalog", 
    "main_custom", 
    array(
        "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "catalog",
        "IBLOCK_ID" => "7",
        "SEF_MODE" => "Y",
        "SEF_FOLDER" => "/shop/catalog/",
        "SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
            "sections" => "",
            "section" => "section/#SECTION_CODE#/",
            "element" => "#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
            "compare" => "compare.php?action=#ACTION_CODE#",
            "smart_filter" => "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/filter/#SMART_FILTER_PATH#/apply/",
        ),
    ),
    false
);
```

Пути точно верные и так вам надо?
Правильнее так:

```php
"SEF_URL_TEMPLATES" => array(
            "sections" => "",
            "section" => "#SECTION_CODE#/", // или "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/",
            "element" => "#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/", // или "#SECTION_CODE_PATH#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/"
```

Answer (score -2):

Если не работает ЧПУ:

1. Проверить что в настройках ЧПУ в инфоблоке.
2. Проверить настройку в компоненте
3. Проверить urlrewrite.php

В urlrewrite.php должна быть запись и указывать должно на реально существующий файл.

по настройкам чпу в компоненте и инфоблоке:

> Если склеить значения "Каталог ЧПУ" и "Страница раздела" и из параметров компонента, у вас должен получиться "URL страницы раздела" из параметров информационного блока, только без макроса #SITE_DIR#. У нас это и там и тут "/novosti/#SECTION_CODE#/", всё верно.

[источник](https://r-morozov.ru/bitrix/kak-sozdat-stranicu-novostej-na-kompleksnom-komponente-v-bitriks-s-chpu/)